# Div element pushed down in Chrome, but not IE or Firefox

Tags: css, google-chrome

I have my page up at http://www.playcademy.com/nolimits_mockup.php, and I am getting a bunch of whitespace below the slideshow in Chrome, though it isn't appearing in Firefox or IE.

When I inspect elements it seems that the headlineArea div is in the correct spot, but everything inside it is about 70px too low.

I'm sure I am missing something basic, but I have no idea what.

Thanks,
Doug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `#slidearea` div is too wide.

```
#slidearea {
display: inline-block;
text-align: center;
position: relative;
width: 915px; /*This was 920px. I narrowed it down to 915px.*/
height: 83px;
overflow: visible;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That solved the issue. If you have a sec, and can tell me why that only causes a problem in Chrome I'd love to understand the inconsistency.

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply a clearfix on headlineArea in order for it to display consistently because it only contains floating child elements.

See: [What methods of ‘clearfix’ can I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211383/which-method-of-clearfix-is-best)